# How to prevent bootstrap label from taking up space and causing shift

Tags: html, css

I have a navbar with a notifications icon.  When there are notifications a label is displayed next to the icon.  However, this label also causes the container to get bigger and everything in my navbar shifts.  I am using flexbox for my navbar.

Here is a basic example of my code:

**html**

```
<ul class="flex-nav">
  <li class="flex-item">
    link
  </li>
  <li class="flex-item">
    linklink
  </li>
  <li class="flex-item">
    <i class="fa fa-bell fa-lg flex-icon"></i>
    <span class="label label-danger label-as-badge">5</span>
  </li>
  <li class="flex-item">
    link
  </li>
  <li class="flex-item">
    linklinklink
  </li>
  <li class="flex-item">
    link
  </li>
</ul>
```

**css**

```
.flex-nav {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: red;
  height: 56px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.flex-item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex-icon {
  text-decoration: none;
  align-items: center;
}

.label-as-badge {
  border-radius: 1em;
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
}

.label {
  display: inline;
  padding: .2em .6em .3em;
  font-size: 75%;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  border-radius: .25em;
}

.label:empty {
  display: none;
}


}
```

**Fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/weuce4du/3/

You can see what I mean by removing the 5 and seeing what happens to the size of the box the notifications icon is in.

Is there a way to keep the notifications container the same size, keep the bell icon centered, and prevent the label from taking up space and causing a shift in the navbar?  I thought I could use z-index so that it sits on top of everything but it doesn't seem to be working.

UPDATE:  The only thing I've come up with is setting a max-width on the container.  The icon still moves slightly but, doesn't cause any of the other nav links to shift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of the relative positioning. You can add a negative margin, like this margin: -10px to the span.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however not exactly what I was looking for.  Adding a negative margin I can move the span around but I need it to sit top left of the bell without changing the size of the container that it's in and without causing the bell to move.

Comment: In that case, you can add the span.label inside the i class="flex-item". Make the <i> relative and the span absolute positioned. Would that be an option?